# authentication header appid deviceid

Tags: proxy

hi guys can someone please explain for me how to setup the below string.

PUT http://proxy.binu.net/client HTTP/1.1[crlf]X-Binu: proto=3, did=ebe468d1408ba38d, appId=2494, flags=0x101006, echo=1635242009399, auth=null, t=1635242009399[crlf]X-Binu-Context: eyJ2IjoyLCJkaWQiOiJlYmU0NjhkMTQwOGJhMzhkIiwiYWlkIjoiIiwidXgiOiIiLCJjIjpbIk1UTiIsICJNVE4iLCAiTU9CSUxFLUxURSIsICI2NTUxMCIsICI2NTUxMCIsICIwIiwgIjIiXSwiYSI6WyIyNDk0IiwgIjk5MDIzIiwgIjMuNC4wIiwgMzc1NDQ3NjIsIDE2MzA5MTc3MTIsIDE2MTQ0NTkxNDksICJNWUEiLCAiIiwgIjEuMi44IiwgIjAiLCAiIiwgIk1YIl0sImQiOlsiSHVhd2VpIiwgIlNURi1MMDkiLCAiOSIsIDcyMCwgMTM2OSwgMi4wMCwgW10sIFtdXSwibCI6WzAuMDAsMC4wMCwiemEiLCJlbi1HQiIsIkFmcmljYS9Kb2hhbm5lc2J1cmciLDAsMC4wMF0sIm1pZCI6IiJ9

Comment: Please provide context on what you are using, what you want to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You tagged it "ibm-appid", is that IBM (Cloud) App ID or something else?

Comment: I need to get access to the proxy 13.244.165.21:80 but the response is 403 which need credentials so heard by using json header which includes appid, deviceid and user agent it can give me 200OK status like below example. User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Redmi 8 Build/PKQ1.190319.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Mobile Safari/537.36 binu/4448 (4f2d48faa1550ccc) [crlf][crlf]

Comment: appid could be anything, not necessarily IBM App ID. It is a common security mechanism

Comment: but in you experience what kind of a header below

Comment: how can i find appid on android phone?